# Are the built-in modules loaded into the memory when we run the program?

Tags: python, module

Are all the built-in modules loaded into the memory when we run the program?

Comment: Do you mean the actual *"‘built-in’ identifiers of Python"*, the functions and modules that are always available (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html), or other standard library modules (which the answer covers)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, they are only loaded when you import them by yourself
Example:

1. import turtle
2. import math
3. import JSON
4. import sqlite3